# mySQL - Pagination of filtered rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a REST service which return rows from a database table depending on the current page and results per page.

When not filtering the results, it's pretty easy to do, I just do a SELECT WHERE id >= (page - 1) * perPage + 1 and LIMIT to perPage.

The problem is when trying to use pagination on filtered results, e.g. if I choose to filter only the rows WHERE type = someType.

In that case, the first match of the first page can start in id 7, and the last can be in id 5046. Then the first match of the second page can start at 7302 and end at 12430, and so on.

For the first page of filtered results, I'd be able to simply start from id 1 and LIMIT to perPage, but for the second page, etc, I need to know the index of the last matched row in the previous page, or even better - the first matched row in the current page, or some other indication.

How do I do it efficiently? I need to be able to do it on tables with millions of rows, so obviously fetching all the rows and taking it from there is not an option.

The idea is something like this:

`SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE filterKey = filterValue AND id >= id_of_first_match_in_current_page`

with id_of_first_match_in_current_page being the mystery.

Comment: This seems a really odd way to do it. Standard for small / medium data sets in my expierence is to ORDER BY the rows so you get a consistent data set (so you can use whatever WHERE), then use LIMIT and, the bit I suspect you may have missed, an OFFSET clause to tell MySQL to return rows from position X.

Comment: How large is the filtered data set typically likely to be?

Comment: Jon - I understand, I wasn't familiar with OFFSET, thank you. Strawberry - I'd like to be able to fetch something like 200 rows at a time, from filtered results which can get to hundreds of thousands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't know what the first id on a given page is, because id numbers are not necessarily sequential. In other words, there could be gaps in the sequence, so rows on the fifth page of 100 rows doesn't necessarily start at id 500. It could start on id 527 for example, It's impossible to know.

Stated yet another way: **id is a value, not a row number.**

One possible solution if your client is advancing through pages in ascending order is that each REST request fetches data, notes the *greatest* id value on that page, then uses that in the *next* REST request so it queries id values that are larger.

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE filterKey = filterValue 
AND id > id_of_last_match_of_previous_page
```

But if your REST request can fetch any random page, this solution doesn't work. It depends on having fetched the prior page already.

Another solution is to use the `LIMIT <x> OFFSET <y>` syntax. This allows you to request any arbitrary page. `LIMIT <y>, <x>` works the same, but for some reason x and y are reversed in the two different syntax forms, so keep that in mind.

Using `LIMIT...OFFSET` isn't very efficient when you request a page that is many pages into the result. Say you request the 5,000th page. MySQL has to generate a result on the server-side of 5,000 pages, then discard 4,999 of them and return the last page in the result. Sorry, but that's how it works.

---

Re your comment:

You must understand that `WHERE` applies conditions on *values* in rows, but pages are defined by the *position* of rows. These are two different ways of determining rows!

If you have a column that is guaranteed to be a **row-number**, then you can use that value like a row position. You can even put an index on it, or use it as the primary key.

But primary key values may change, and may not be consecutive, for example if you update or delete rows, or rollback some transactions, and so on. Renumbering primary key values is a bad idea because other tables or external data may reference primary key values.

So you could add another column that is *not* the primary key, but only a row-number.

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN row_number BIGINT UNSIGNED, ADD KEY (row_number);
```

Then fill the values when you need to renumber the rows.

```
SET @row := 0;
UPDATE MyTable SET row_number = (@row := @row + 1) ORDER BY id;
```

You'd have to re-number the rows if you ever delete some, for example. It's not efficient to do this frequently, depending on the size of the table.

Also, new inserts cannot create correct row number values without locking the table. This is necessary to prevent race conditions.

If you have a guarantee that `row_number` is a sequence of consecutive values, then it's both a value and a row position, so you can use it for high-performance index lookups for any arbitrary page of rows.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE row_number BETWEEN 401 AND 500;
```

At least until the next time the sequence of row numbers is put into doubt by a delete or by new inserts.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Is there an efficient approach that allows me to request any arbitrary page? Nowadays with all the advancements in big data someone must have thought of something.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the ID column for the wrong purpose.  ID is the *identifier* of a record, not the *sequence number* of a record for any given set of results.

The `LIMIT` keyword extends to basic pagination.  If you just wanted the first 10 records, you'd do something like:

```
LIMIT 10
```

To paginate, if you wanted the *second* 10 records, you'd do:

```
LIMIT 10,10
```

The 10 after that:

```
LIMIT 20,10
```

And so on.

The `LIMIT` clause is independent of the `WHERE` clause.  Use `WHERE` to filter your results, use `LIMIT` to paginate them.