# Get X rows after the row with id(UUID) = "..."

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to implement cursor-based pagination. I want to get X rows after the row with id 'abcd'. (Note, I cannot do something like `where id > 123` since my primary ID column is a UUID.)

The traditional way of solving this would be to use `LIMIT x OFFSET y`, however if a new record was inserted at the top of the list while the user is navigating between pages, records from previous pages would be included in subsequent pages. I need to prevent that and say, "get 3 records after the row with id 'F'.

Thanks!

Comment: `limit` supports both number and offset parameters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mySQL - Pagination of filtered rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40552894/mysql-pagination-of-filtered-rows)

Comment: What do you mean "order the table arbitrarily" ? in the vast majority of cases doing something that works depending on your methodology of ordering will be much more efficient than a generic solution (which requires attaching an order indicator column to the result set)

Comment: @apokryfos I just meant that the order could be other than by ID (although since my IDs are strings, that wouldn't make sense anyway.)

Comment: @underscore_d This isn't a duplicate because this is related to cursor-based pagination, not offset/page based like the one you linked. The reason I need cursor-based pagination is so each page never includes duplicates from the previous page (which would be the case if a new record was inserted at the top of the list while the user is navigating through the pages.)

Comment: Strings can be ordered. The fact that they are UUIDs will make that ordering arbitrary. I don't see a problem.

Comment: @underscore_d I think you misunderstand my problem. I've edited my post to clarify.

Comment: I think I understand now, but I also think you're overengineering a solution to a problem everyone expects to happen occasionally. At any rate you are right. I don't know exactly the specifics but you can presumably make a stored procedure with a cursor and start returning results after you've encountered a specific id

Comment: But then that row has to exist among a non-arbitrary order. So some other column(s) have to provide that.

Comment: @underscore_d the order is deterministic (`published_at` in my case.) Please see the answer and demo I've just posted for an example of what I needed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49942306/get-x-rows-after-the-row-with-iduuid/49945405#49945405 If you have any recommendations to improve it I'd love to hear! :)

Comment: "order my table arbitrarily" implied that the specific order didn't matter, perhaps with the further implication that it had to be deterministic (if not specific). That contradicts the revelation that you actually want to order by `published_at`. I'm probably just missing it- but why not, then, paginate based on that, rather than by the UUID?

Comment: Apologies, by 'arbitrary' I just meant 'an order which isn't the same order they are in the table'. I've updated my question to be more clear. Using the `published_at` column for pagination was something I considered but we also need to order by other columns, so I think a generic solution is preferable in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @apokryfos (and another person who originally led me down the correct path but unfortunately deleted his answer! ), I've managed to put together an acceptable example of cursor-based pagination in action.

**DEMO:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/824f28/54/0

**Schema:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `published_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `test`
    (`id`, `published_at`)
VALUES
    ('a','2011-02-12 14:53:27'),
    ('b','2010-05-21 14:53:27'),
    ('c','2012-03-30 14:53:27'),
    ('d','2011-09-30 14:53:27'),
    ('e','2011-08-30 14:53:27'),
    ('f','2010-09-26 14:53:27'),
    ('g','2010-05-13 14:53:27'),
    ('h','2011-04-12 14:53:27'),
    ('i','2010-12-23 14:53:27');
```

**Query:**

```sql
SELECT id, published_at FROM (
    SELECT *, @track:=IF(@track=0 AND id = 'i', @track+1, @track) AS toInclude
    FROM  `test`
    ORDER BY published_at
) a, (SELECT @track:=0) b
WHERE toInclude = 1
ORDER BY published_at
LIMIT 3 OFFSET 1
```

Result:

```
| id  | published_at         |
|-----|----------------------|
|  a  | 2011-02-12T14:53:27Z |
|  h  | 2011-04-12T14:53:27Z |
|  e  | 2011-08-30T14:53:27Z |
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok a bit of a hack but might just work:

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT stuff_to_select FROM (
SELECT @rank:=IF(@rank=0 AND id = 'abcd', 1, @rank) AS rank, stuff_to_select 
  FROM table
  ORDER BY arbitrary_order_by
  ) t WHERE rank > 0 LIMIT pagesize
```

The idea is to keep rank 0 until you hit the ID you want and then then switch it to 1 and select everything that happened after that switch. I'm sure there's like a million caveats and gotchas to this approach so use with caution.

Also as you may have noticed it does 2 selects from a potentially large result set.